# Natively dark CSS framework

Tags: framework, css, dark-theme

I'm looking for a CSS framework which natively includes a dark theming (no additional code required to change colors etc.).

Preferably Material or Flat design compliant, but not required.

Answer (score 1):

There are some CSS frameworks out there that they are dark i recommend you using [**ModestaCSS**](https://github.com/AlexFlipnote/ModestaCSS.git) if you want native dark CSS framework. Also there are some bootstrap themes that they are available in [bootswatch](https://bootswatch.com/darkly/)

Comment: Unfortunately, ModestaCSS is not as complete as light CSS frameworks are, and boostwatch isn't up to date. Thanks for answering though.